# file.exists() returns false on Android

Tags: android

```
    String filename = "file:///android_asset/Help_ja.html";
    File f = new File(filename);
    if (!f.exists()) filename="file:///android_asset/Help_us.html";
    webView.loadUrl(filename);
```

i load an HTML out of the assests folder, both files are there, when i tried this code:

```
filename="file:///android_asset/Help_us.html";
webView.loadUrl(filename);
```

it worked, but for some reason f.exists() returns false, i was thinking maybe its because a URL, but then how do i check if the file exists before i load it to the webView?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's suppose you have two file paths:

```
String originalPath = "file:///android_asset/..."
String localizedPath = "file:///android_asset/..."
```

The following will test for the existence of the second and default to the first if not available:

```
String localizedAssetPath = localizedPath.replace("file:///android_asset/",  "");
try {
  InputStream stream = getResources().getAssets().open(localizedAssetPath);
  stream.close();
  return localizedPath;
}
catch (Exception e) {
  return originalPath;
}
```

So, basically, you remove the `file:///android_asset/` base path and you try to open it as a stream. If this fails, you default to the original path.

Answer (score 3):

In code a solution that works for me:

```
private static boolean assetExists(AssetManager assets, String name) {
    try {
        // using File to extract path / filename
        // alternatively use name.lastIndexOf("/") to extract the path
        File f = new File(name);
        String parent = f.getParent();
        if (parent == null) parent = "";
        String fileName = f.getName();
        // now use path to list all files
        String[] assetList = assets.list(parent);
        if (assetList != null && assetList.length > 0) {
            for (String item : assetList) {
                if (fileName.equals(item))
                    return true;
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Log.w(TAG, e); // enable to log errors
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // test for file:///android_asset/Help_ja.html
    boolean exists1 = assetExists(getAssets(), "Help_ja.html"));
    // and if assets are in subfolders
    // would be ./assets/www/test2.hml in your project
    boolean exists2 = assetExists(getAssets(), "www/test2.html");
}
```

Asset files are not physical files on the device, so you can't use `File` for them. The only way to read their content is through the `AssetManager`. Above example code uses the `list()` method to list the asset files and check the list for the one you search. You could also try to open an `InputStream` for example.

Answer (score 1):

A file doesn't take a URL, it takes a path.  So it should not start with File:///,  it should start with / for an absolute path or the first directory name for a relative path.

If you need to check if it exists before loading it into a URL, strip the protocol from the string before passing to the File constructor.  If you load the URL into a URL object you can use getPath() and getFile() as helpers

Comment: Don't have time to test this, but something like this should work:

URL url = new URL(filename);
File file = new File(url.getPath()+url.getFile());

Possibly you'd need to add a "/" between the path and the file, I don't know if url adds a terminator or not.

Comment: `/android_asset/Help_us.html` will not exist as well since it's a virtual thing only. You can't check if asset files exist via `File` since they are not represented by actual files in the file-system. Use [Context#getAssets()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getAssets%28%29) and possible the `list()` method there.